# Duplicate firebase push notifications in react js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have integrated firebase web push notifications in my react CRA app. I am using `"firebase": "^9.14.0",`. When I am triggering the notification from backend/firebase console I am receiving the notifications twice in my mobile which I have enabled the notifications for the application.

```
//firebase-messaging-sw.js

// Scripts for firebase and firebase messaging
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js');
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: " ",
    authDomain: " ",
    projectId: " ",
    storageBucket: " ",
    messagingSenderId: " ",
    appId: " ",
    measurementId: " "
  };

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Retrieve firebase messaging
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log('Received background message ', payload);

  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.notification.body,
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove 'self.registration' it work

```
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
  console.log('Received background message: ', payload);

  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.notification.body,
  };

  // self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
  //   notificationOptions);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).